# Struct and array - Error: Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to put two tables together using struct and array. My idea is for each row in table A apply Levenshtein Distance to table B.

Table A:

```
col1
whisky
delta
Tango
```

Table B

```
col1
Whiskey
delta force
Tango is great
```

Desired output:

```
col1        col2             col3
whisky    Whiskey            <lv_distance_score>
          delta force        <lv_distance_score>
          Tango is great     <lv_distance_score>
delta     Whiskey            <lv_distance_score>
          delta force        <lv_distance_score>
          Tango is great     <lv_distance_score>
Tango     Whiskey            <lv_distance_score>
          delta force        <lv_distance_score>
          Tango is great     <lv_distance_score>
```

For this, first I'm trying to just get de desired output of col1 and col2, but I keep getting an `error` that says `Scalar subquery produced more than one element`.

The query I wrote is:

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT col1, [STRUCT((SELECT col1 FROM table_B))] AS col2 FROM table_A
)
SELECT col1,c2 FROM a,UNNEST(a.col2) AS c2;
```

What I'm doing wrong here? How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I'm doing wrong here?

Below is simple fix for your original query

```
WITH a AS (
SELECT col1, 
  [STRUCT(ARRAY(SELECT col1 FROM table_B) as col2)] AS col2 
FROM table_A
)
SELECT col1, c2.col2 
FROM a, UNNEST(a.col2) AS c2;
```

While above hopefully shows you what was wrong with your query - I am not sure it is right direction to go.

> How can I achieve what I'm looking for?

you just go with simple cross join like in below example

```
SELECT a.col1, ARRAY_AGG(b.col1 ORDER BY lv_distance_score(a.col1, b.col1) LIMIT 1)
FROM table_A a 
CROSS JOIN table_B b
GROUP BY a.col1
```

Note: you can find plenty of examples for Levenshtein Distance UDF here on SO

Comment: glad it helped you.  consider voting the answer if it was helpful :o)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit lost.  Why not just use a `cross join`?

```
select a.col1, b.col1
from a cross join
     b
```

If you want one row per row in `a` with an array for b, then:

```
select a.col1, array_agg(b)
from a cross join
     b
group by a.col1;
```

Comment: Hi @Gordon Linoff. Maybe I'm the one who is lost. The cross join will give me the cartesian product of the two tables, right? I don't need all the `lv_distance_scores`, just the best one (the closest to 0). That's why I thought that it would be a better idea to get that table (plus I'm still learning BigQuery/SQL and still practicing all this beyond just selects and inserts, so also thought that would be a good instance to practice this). If I'm wrong, please correct me :)

Comment: @PedroPabloSeverinHonorato . . . Your sample data is showing a cross join.